# AttributeError: module 'pandas.plotting._matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I am at a complete loss as to what is causing this problem, so hopefully someone here can help.  Basically, I have built a GUI application using PyQt5 that works perfectly when ran as a .py file, no errors at all, but when I converted it to an .exe file using cx_freeze, my plotting function breaks, returning the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main2.py", line 266, in randomForest
  File "C:\Users\tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 972, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
AttributeError: module 'pandas.plotting._matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'
```

Again, this function works in a .py file, but not in the .exe. Below is the relevant code that it's trying to run.

```
# Importing modules / libraries
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as Navi
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import sip
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

# Canvas class to display the graph
class MatplotlibCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    # Setting graph dimensions
    def __init__(self,parent=None, dpi = 120):
        # Creating figure
        fig = Figure(dpi = dpi)

        # Create axes and add them to the figure as subplots
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        
        super(MatplotlibCanvas,self).__init__(fig)
        
        # Setting figure layout
        fig.tight_layout()

# UI class
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # Create UI
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # Create MainWindow
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(947, 633)

        # Create centralwidget
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # Layout centralwidget in a grid
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        # Create horizontal layout to hold the buttons
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        # Button to activate the random forest classifier, and it to the horizontal layout
        self.randomForestButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.randomForestButton.setObjectName("randomForestButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.randomForestButton)

        # Button to activate the SVM classifier, and it to the horizontal layout
        self.svmButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.svmButton.setObjectName("svmButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.svmButton)

        # Button to activate the isolation forest algorithm, and it to the horizontal layout
        self.isolationForestButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.isolationForestButton.setObjectName("isolationForestButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.isolationForestButton)

        # Button to activate the One-Class SVM algorithm, and it to the horizontal layout
        self.oneclassSVMButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.oneclassSVMButton.setObjectName("oneclassSVMButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.oneclassSVMButton)

        # Create horizontal spacer
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)

        # Specifying dimensions of the horizontal layout
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        # Create second horizontal layout for the labels
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        for i in range(101):
            self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        for i in range(101):
            self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        for i in range(101):
            self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_3)
        
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
        
        self.comboBox_4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_4.setObjectName("comboBox_4")
        for i in range(101):
            self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_4)
        
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5)
        
        self.comboBox_5 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_5.setObjectName("comboBox_5")
        for i in range(5):
            self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_5)
        
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(self.spacerItem2)
        
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 947, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        
        self.actionOpen_CSV_File = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_CSV_File.setObjectName("actionOpen_CSV_File")
        
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_CSV_File)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.randomForestButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Random Forest"))
        self.svmButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SVM"))
        self.isolationForestButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Isolation Forest"))
        self.oneclassSVMButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "One-Class SVM"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test_size"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "random_state (train/test split)"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "n_estimators"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "random_state (classifier)"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "kernel"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionOpen_CSV_File.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open CSV File"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

        self.iterator1 = 0
        self.iterator2 = 0
        self.num1 = 0.0
        self.num2 = 0
        for i in range(101):
            self.comboBox.setItemText(self.iterator1, _translate("MainWindow", str(round(self.num1, 2))))
            self.iterator1 += 1
            self.num1 += 0.01
        for i in range(101):
            self.comboBox_2.setItemText(self.iterator2, _translate("MainWindow", str(round(self.num2, 2))))
            self.comboBox_3.setItemText(self.iterator2, _translate("MainWindow", str(round(self.num2, 2))))
            self.comboBox_4.setItemText(self.iterator2, _translate("MainWindow", str(round(self.num2, 2))))
            self.iterator2 += 1
            self.num2 += 1

        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "linear"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "poly"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "rbf"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "sigmoid"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "precomputed"))
        
        self.filename = ''
        self.canv = MatplotlibCanvas(self)

        self.actionOpen_CSV_File.triggered.connect(self.getFile)
        self.randomForestButton.clicked.connect(self.randomForest)
        self.svmButton.clicked.connect(self.SVM)
        self.isolationForestButton.clicked.connect(self.isolationForest)
        self.oneclassSVMButton.clicked.connect(self.oneclassSVM)
        
    def getFile(self):
        self.filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter = "csv (*.csv)")[0]
        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.filename,encoding = 'utf-8').fillna(0)

    def randomForest(self):
        # Random forest classifier for the machine temperature system failure data
        y = self.df['Fault'].values
        X = self.df.drop(['Fault'], axis = 1)

        # Establishing training and testing sets.
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = float(self.comboBox.currentText()), random_state = int(self.comboBox_2.currentText()))

        # Defining the random forest classifier and fitting the model to the data
        model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = int(self.comboBox_3.currentText()), random_state = int(self.comboBox_4.currentText()))
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)

        # Predicting the classes
        prediction_test = model.predict(X_test)

        accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, prediction_test)
        
        percentage = "{:.2%}".format(accuracy)
            
        # Displaying prediction accuracy
        print("Accuracy = ", percentage)

        self.toolbar = Navi(self.canv,self.centralwidget)

        try:
            self.horizontalLayout.removeWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.verticalLayout.removeWidget(self.canv)

            sip.delete(self.toolbar)
            sip.delete(self.canv)
            self.toolbar = None
            self.canv = None
            self.verticalLayout.removeItem(self.spacerItem2)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

        self.canv = MatplotlibCanvas(self)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.canv)

        self.canv.axes.cla()
        self.ax = self.canv.axes
            
        if self.filename.find("temperature.csv") != -1:
            self.df = pd.read_csv("machine_temperature_system_failure.csv")

            self.df.plot(ax = self.canv.axes)

            self.ax.set_xlabel('timestamp')
            self.ax.set_ylabel('values')
            self.ax.set_title(str(percentage))
            self.ax.get_legend().remove()

            self.canv.draw()
        else:
            self.df.plot(ax = self.canv.axes)

            self.ax.set_xlabel('timestamp')
            self.ax.set_ylabel('values')
            self.ax.set_title(str(percentage))
            self.ax.get_legend().remove()

            self.canv.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A few things I've tried, based on similar questions I've seen here:

importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Uninstalling, updating, and reinstalling pandas.

Uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib

I have generated the .exe using pyinstaller, cx_freeze, and py2exe and the error has occured in all of them.  cx_freeze is the one I would prefer to use.

Comment: That traceback seems incomplete, did try to run your code from a terminal/prompt to get the *full* traceback?

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I did run the code from a terminal, that is the only traceback that generates. For context, the way the program works is I can load a dataset from a .csv file, then use a series of combo box inputs to set up different classification algorithms to run on the data, and then press a button to plot the dataset and display the accuracy of the classification.  The accuracy will display in the terminal, so that part runs, but the error occurs when it tries to run the plot code.

Comment: Could you please add the code of you `setup.py` script to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the exact same error while using python package `cx_Freeze` to freeze an app I developed with Python's `Tkinter`.

I could solve the issue by changing the `setup.py` script. On the options section of `cx_Freeze.setup()` function, inside "build_exe" it is possible to include explicitly any package, specially for third party packages.

Here is an example of a `setup.py` script, where I included in `packages_included` some packages that gave me trouble:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
    
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("main.py", base=base, icon='Logo.ico')]

packages_included = ["tkinter", "matplotlib", "seaborn", "cefpython3", "dash", 
                     "pyodbc","numpy", "pandas", "pandastable"]

packages_excluded = ["scipy", "skimage", "scikit-learn","xlsxwriter", "xml", 
                     "xmlrpc","xarray", "tables", "statsmodels","sqlalchemy", 
                     "tornado","sphinx", "openpyxl", "lxml","jupyter_core",
                     "jupyter_server", "jupyter_client",
                     "ipykernel", "ipython_genutils","ipywidgets", "h5py", 
                     "distributed","defusedxml", "dask",
                     "docutils","cryptography", "bs4"]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Risk Tracker",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":packages_included,
                             "excludes":packages_excluded,
                             "include_files":["Logo.png", "Logo.ico"]}},
    version = '0.01',
    description = "Application for tracking risk",
    executables = executables
    )
```

In fact, some of the problems that appear with dependencies of some packages like circular import errors (like with `seaborn` or `pandastable`) or missing modules can be solved just by explicitly including that package.